# tika parser not parsing the content in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-tika

i am writing a mapreduce job, where it takes a zip file as input,
zip file contains different types of documents such as docx odt pdf txt,
i am using tika parser to parse the documents.

here's the code snippet of my mapper method

```
public void map(Text key, BytesWritable value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ------------------------------
    ------------------------------
        logger.info("Length:\t" + value.getLength());
        byte[] bytesbefore = value.getBytes();
        logger.info("CONTENT BEFORE" + new String(bytesbefore));
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesbefore);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        String mimeType = new Tika().detect(in);
        metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(
                value.getLength());
        try {
            parser.parse(in, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            logger.info(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e1) {
            logger.info(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        in.close();
        logger.info("Content AFTER" + handler.toString());

    ------------------------------        
    ------------------------------
                   }
```

output is written to hbase,

content of the document is empty after parsing

am i missing anything here??

Comment: Have you made sure that you have the Tika Parser jar on your classpath, along with the dependencies? If you ask DefaultParser what parsers it wraps, does it return any? (My hunch is that you're missing some of the parser jars, so have no parsers)

Comment: tika parser jars are in classpath, otherwise i would have got classnot found exception

Comment: AutoDetectParser lives in the Tika Core jar, but it doesn't do anything without any available parsers. They all live in the Tika Parsers (and friends) jars

Comment: both tika parser and tika core present in my classpath, what other jars am i missing?

Comment: All of the dependencies! Ask Maven and it'll tell you what they are, or with the right plugins bundle them up for you

Comment: When tika-parsers is not present the api fallback to EmptyParser without  exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969051/how-to-get-the-text-content-files-with-tika-1-6/29150110#29150110