# How to get the text content files with tika 1.6?

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-tika

Hi i try get the text content from any files in this list pdf,txt,doc,docx and odt
the implementation with tika previously worked fine but now is broken,
The code is it:

```

```
public void uploadFile(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
 UploadedFile file = event.getUploadedFile();
 byte[] data = file.getData();
 Tika tika = new Tika();
 string = tika.parseToString(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
 ...
}
```

```

Any ideas? , bad implementation ?

Comment: Do you have all of the Tika jars on your classpath, along with all of their dependencies?

Comment: i use maven and add tika with this code
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>

[Tika reference](http://tika.apache.org/1.4/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: That'll do you for compiling, but are you sure they're correctly going into your deployment as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add tika-parsers.

For example with maven add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And you can use Auto-Detect Parser:

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
try {
    parser.parse(is, handler, metadata);
    text = handler.toString();
} catch(TikaException te) {
    System.out.println(te.toString());
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```